# Make link with full current URL into thymeleaf view

Tags: thymeleaf

My current request URL is **domain.com/my-action?p1=1&p2=2** and I want to make an anchor like **domain.com/my-action?p1=1&p2=2#anchor**

I tried to use `<a th:href="@{__${#request.requestURI}__#anchor}">My anchor with full query string</a>`

or `<a th:href="@{__${#request.queryString}__#anchor}">My anchor with full query string</a>`

or without preprocessing expression like `<a th:href="${#request.queryString} + '#anchor'">My anchor with full query string</a>`

and `<a th:href="${#request.requestURI} + '#anchor'">My anchor with full query string</a>`

This doesn't work in the two cases:

- No problem with the `requestURI` but the link is without query string parameters (**domain.com/my-action#anchor**)
- with the `queryString` the template fail on parsing and I have an error in console that say "Access to request parameters is forbbiden in this context. Not some restrictions apply to variable access. For exampledirect access to request parameters is forbbiden in preprocessing and unescaped expressions, in TEXT template mode, in fragment insertion specifications, and in some specific attributes processors."

My search result about this problem returns this issue: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/648 but I don't understand how to fix that.

If someone has an idea about how to make this anchor link as well ;)

**EDIT:** My application is a spring boot 2.2.2 application with `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` ; `thymeleaf-3.0.11.REALEASE` ; `thymeleaf-expression-processor-1.1.3` and `thymeleaf-layout-dialect-2.4.1`

Comment: In case it helps: Thymeleaf doesn't _force_ you to use the [link URL syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#link-urls) when building an `href` value. You can use standard string concatenation: `"${foo} + 'literal' + ${bar}"`. Also, just curious as to why you need [pre-processing expressions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#preprocessing). They are awesome, but can make markup more complicated, if they are not strictly necessary.

Comment: Yes. But if I test like `th:href="${#request.requestURI} + '#anchor'"` or `th:href="${#request.queryString} + '#anchor'"` I have the same problem. But you're probably right...

Comment: OK - sorry that was not helpful. Two more thoughts: I have not seen the `#request` object used like this before: `${#request.queryString}`. I am more used to seeing things like this: `${#request.getContextPath()}`.  So, how about `${#request.getQueryString()}` - i.e. using the explicit method call?  Failing that, how about solving the problem by side-stepping it (my favorite way)? Don't access `#request` directly in Thymeleaf. Instead, build the `href` string in your code which generates the Thymeleaf model, and pass that into your template instead.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help. I going to test with href string that you say...

If someone else has an answer on the thymeleaf way you're welcome ;)